# manualy changing package name in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

In eclipse, I change the package name by going to `right click on project >> android tools >> rename application package`.

Then it displays the manifest xml and the new to be changed one.

Is eclipse doing anything else in the project when changing the package name (besides changing the manifest file)?

Will the app work just the same if I manually change the package name in the `androidmanifest.xml` instead of the above?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the package name that is displayed in your manifest to any you like. 
After changing it clean and rebuild your project.
You might get some errors in your classes. All you need to do in those classes is "Ctrl+Shift+O" it will reorganize your import for the R.java class references.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your application will work as it is.Your package name in every activity and in androidmanifest.xml will change only by this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are `refactoring` package name, all the classes and references to these classes (from other class) will change. Also `manifest.xml` contains component classes that are being used. So these names will also change.

Your project will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't refactor the package name?
Project > src > right click on package > Refactor > Rename

or single click on package name, then press: Alt + Shift + R

and then clean your project